# problems were detected while vaidating & converting Ecore models. The names are not well formed for model objects in diagram

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I tried to install the EMF plugin inside eclipse but some of the default Ecore diagram and EMF Generator Model projects were not available.
So downloaded a different eclipse installer for modelling  i.e. Eclipse Modeling Tools (275 MB ) and found all the relevant model related & diagram based project now.
I have followed the same tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html .
I was able to create the webpage model diagram & then the webpage.ecore file but then the  webpage.genmodel the model generator file was giving errors like the ” **names used in the diagrams for the objects are not well formed** ” in webpage model diagram .
I googled for these errors which according to me mean that the names are not proper according to the given language for modeling constraints & no resolution to these errors were found.
then tried to ignore the errors and tried Generating the domain classes for java code, java code is generated but then the other following modules **Create your model** & **Edit your model** under **Run your plugins** category does not work further due to the previous errors on this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html.
Please help me debug these errors

Answer (score 0):

check if Name property is not null , you need to fill it

http://emftools.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=emfvb:quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of `Epackage` and also prefix and URI

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/golTN.jpg)

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEk6F.jpg)